# Converting string to date error when the day part is a single digit?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert a string column [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZGqw.gif) to date using

```
df2$DATE_PAYMENT <- as.Date(df$DATE_PAYMENT, format ="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I found it works fine when the value is `ddmmyyyy`, but gives "NA" if it the day part only has one digit as `dmmyyyy`, e.g., `2092017` (`Sep 2, 2017`).

Is there a way around this?

Thank you!

Comment: That is an ambiguous format. Is is 2 September or 20 September. If you know it has to be the former, pad the date with an extra zero.

Comment: Do single digit months appear as well?

Comment: `as.Date(ifelse(nchar(dates) == 7, paste0('0',dates), dates), format ="%d%m%Y")` in case months do have leading zeros...

Comment: Please do not post your data as an image. We don't want to type it all in. If you have the data in R, please use `dput(MyData)` to create a text format that you can paste into your question and we can cut and paste for testing. If the data is too long,  just use `dput(head(MyData, 10))`

Answer (score 1):

Try lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(2092017)
```